# How to implement a range slider using swiftUI where the starting value is not zero

Tags: swift, swiftui, slider

I'm trying to create a range slider for a person's height where
the minimum height of **3ft** shall also be the starting point of the range slider.

The code below shows a range slider with a starting point of **0ft** how can I modify it to start at **3ft**

**Expected Range Slider Design**

[image: Expected Range slider Design]

**Current Range Slider**

[image: Current Range slider based on code]

**Code for Current Range Slider**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var heightMinValue: Double = 0.4 * Constants.Range.size // 40% of Constants.Range.size
    @State var heightMaxValue: Double = Constants.Range.size
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HeightRangeSliderView(scaleMinValue: $heightMinValue, scaleMaxValue: $heightMaxValue, minimumpercentageVal: 40, lableWidth: 89)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct HeightRangeSliderView: View {
    /// ` Slider` Binding min & max values
    @Binding var scaleMinValue: Double
    @Binding var scaleMaxValue: Double
    var minimumpercentageVal: Double
    var leftKnobWidth: Double = 28
    var leftKnobHeight: Double = 28
    var rightKnobWidth: Double = 28
    var rightKnobHeight: Double = 28
    var barWidth: Double = Constants.Range.size
    var leftKnobColor = Color.white
    var rightKnobColor = Color.white
    var backgroundTrackColor = Color.DesignSystem.Divider
    var selectedTrackColor = Color.DesignSystem.Active
    /// Slider min & max static and dynamic labels value color
    var sliderMinMaxValuesColor = Color.DesignSystem.Active
    /// Set slider min & max Label values
    var lableWidth: Double = 55
    var lableColor = Color.DesignSystem.FieldBg

    var minLabel: String {
        String(format: "%.0f", (CGFloat(scaleMinValue) / barWidth) * 100)
    }
    var maxLabel: String {
        String(format: "%.0f", (CGFloat(scaleMaxValue) / barWidth) * 100)
    }
    private let heightformatStyle = Measurement<UnitLength>.FormatStyle(width: .abbreviated, usage: .personHeight)
    var heightMinValue: Measurement<UnitLength> {
        Measurement(value: (scaleMinValue / barWidth) * 100, unit: UnitLength.inches)
    }
    var heightMaxValue: Measurement<UnitLength> {
        Measurement(value: (scaleMaxValue / barWidth) * 100, unit: UnitLength.inches)
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            /// `Slider` start & end static values show in view
            HStack {
                // start value
                Text(heightMinValue, format: heightformatStyle)
                    .monospacedDigit()
                    .frame(width: lableWidth, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(sliderMinMaxValuesColor)
                    .background(lableColor, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
                Spacer()
                // end value
                Text(heightMaxValue, format: heightformatStyle)
                    .monospacedDigit()
                    .frame(width: lableWidth, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(sliderMinMaxValuesColor)
                    .background(lableColor, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
            }
            .frame(width: (barWidth + (rightKnobWidth * 2)))
            .padding(.horizontal)

            /// `Slider` track view
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // background track view
                Capsule()
                    .fill(backgroundTrackColor)
                    .frame(width: (barWidth + (rightKnobWidth * 2)), height: 6)

                // selected track view
                Capsule()
                    .fill(selectedTrackColor)
                    .frame(width: scaleMaxValue - scaleMinValue, height: 6)
                    .offset(x: scaleMinValue + rightKnobWidth)

                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    // minimum value glob view
                    Circle()
                        .fill(leftKnobColor)
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 12, x: 0, y: 6)
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 0.5)
                        .frame(width: leftKnobWidth, height: leftKnobHeight)
                        .offset(x: scaleMinValue)
                        .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ value in
                            /// drag validation
                            if value.location.x >= 0 && value.location.x <= scaleMaxValue {
                                scaleMinValue = value.location.x
                            }
                        })
                        )

                    // maximum value glob view
                    Circle()
                        .fill(rightKnobColor)
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 12, x: 0, y: 6)
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 0.5)
                        .frame(width: rightKnobWidth, height: rightKnobHeight)
                        .offset(x: scaleMaxValue)
                        .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ value in
                            /// drag validation
                            if value.location.x <= barWidth && value.location.x >= scaleMinValue {
                                scaleMaxValue = value.location.x
                            }
                        })
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum Constants {
    enum Range {
        static let size = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100
    }
}

extension Color {
    enum DesignSystem {
        public static let Active = Color.green
        public static let FieldBg = Color.black
        public static let Divider = Color.gray
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you designed your slider is very confusing. If this is a slider for selecting a `Measurement<UnitLength>`, why are the minimum and maximum values bindings of `Double`s, which represent a percentage of the screen's width? The screen's width has nothing to do with this.

Comment: the screen's width was to make it dynamic for different screen sizes

Comment: let me try minimum and maximum values binding Measurement<UnitLength>, Thanks

Comment: minimum and maximum values need to be double because of all the width calculations

Comment: You shouldn't calculate widths based on `UIScreen.main.bounds` in the first place. Use a `GeometryReader` to read the size of the view, and calculate based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about this in terms of `Measurement`s, and not screen coordinates. There are 4 measurement values that is relevant:

- the minimum value of the slider (`rangeMinValue`)
- the maximum value of the slider (`rangeMaxValue`)
- the currently selected minimum value (`heightMinValue`)
- the urrently selected maximum value (`heightMaxValue`)

From those, we can form two ranges. The length of those ranges can be useful to our calculations too, so let's call them `range` (= `rangeMaxValue - rangeMinValue`) and `heightRange` (= `heightMaxValue - heightMinValue`).

This is how it looks like in code:

```
@Binding var heightMinValue: Measurement<UnitLength>
@Binding var heightMaxValue: Measurement<UnitLength>

var heightRange: Measurement<UnitLength> {
    heightMaxValue - heightMinValue
}

let rangeMinValue: Measurement<UnitLength>
let rangeMaxValue: Measurement<UnitLength>

var range: Measurement<UnitLength> {
    rangeMaxValue - rangeMinValue
}
```

We will need the slider's (not the screen's) width as well. That can be read by a `GeometryReader`. Let's wrap one of those around the `ZStack`:

```
// You don't need to use barWidth!
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of using the above values to calculate what each of the four components of the `ZStack` (the two capsules and two circles) should have as their width and offsets:

```
// in the ZStack
let trackWidth = geometry.size.width - leftKnobWidth / 2 - rightKnobWidth / 2
// background track view
Capsule()
    .fill(backgroundTrackColor)
    .frame(width: trackWidth, height: 8)
    .offset(x: leftKnobWidth / 2)

// selected track view
Capsule()
    .fill(selectedTrackColor)
    .frame(width: trackWidth * (heightRange / range), height: 8)
    .offset(x: trackWidth * ((heightMinValue - rangeMinValue) / range) + leftKnobWidth / 2)

// minimum value glob view
Circle()
    .fill(leftKnobColor)
    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 12, x: 0, y: 6)
    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 0.5)
    .frame(width: leftKnobWidth, height: leftKnobHeight)
    .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ value in
        // I think it's easier to use translation, rather than location
        heightMinValue.value += range * (value.translation.width / trackWidth).value
        // clamp the selected value
        heightMinValue.value = max(min(heightMinValue.value, heightMaxValue.value), rangeMinValue.value)
    })
    )
    .offset(x: trackWidth * ((heightMinValue - rangeMinValue) / range))

// maximum value glob view
Circle()
    .fill(rightKnobColor)
    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 12, x: 0, y: 6)
    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 0.5)
    .frame(width: rightKnobWidth, height: rightKnobHeight)
    .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ value in
        let x = range * value.translation.width / trackWidth
        heightMaxValue.value += x.value
        heightMaxValue.value = min(max(heightMinValue.value, heightMaxValue.value), rangeMaxValue.value)
    })
    )
    .offset(x: trackWidth * ((heightMaxValue - rangeMinValue) / range))
```

Note that I overloaded `/` for `Measurement`s to make this more readable:

```
func /(lhs: Measurement<UnitLength>, rhs: Measurement<UnitLength>) -> CGFloat {
    CGFloat(lhs.converted(to: .meters).value / rhs.converted(to: .meters).value)
}
```

The two labels are alright, but you don't need to set their width explicitly to `barWidth`. The automatically-determined width does what you want already.

Example usage:

```
VStack {
    HeightRangeSliderView(
        heightMinValue: $heightMinValue,
        heightMaxValue: $heightMaxValue,
        rangeMinValue: Measurement(value: 40, unit: UnitLength.inches),
        rangeMaxValue: Measurement(value: 100, unit: UnitLength.inches),
        lableWidth: 89)
}
.frame(height: 200)
.padding()
```